# Monogame Pipeline file size too big

Tags: pipeline, monogame

The .xnb files that the Monogame pipeline creates are way too big. I have a folder of images that makes up 8 mb. When passed through the pipeline and published for installing creates 2 gb of .xnb files... that's a little bit of a problem.

Example: An image (png) is 32,6 kB, gets turned into a .xnb.deploy worth 10,1 MB.

I'm not sure what to do about this. There must be something obvious I'm missing because I feel it shouldn't be this way at all, am I missing some compression setting in the pipeline and if so where do I find it? Thanks

Edit: Tried in both Debug and release, same result.

Edit 2: I've tried many of the solutions that I've found on the internet without any luck. I've tried to set the content pipeline settings to Compress - True but that did nothing.

I've tried to go through every image(around 500) and turning the TextureFormat to DxtCompressed, I had an error that I needed to have the ResizeToPower set as True, so I did that and tried again. This gave me the error "processor textureprocessor had unexpected failure" and I could not find a solution to that... so I gave up on that idea.

I also tried following this link http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/forum/t-904011/xnb-compression but could not find the "compress content pipeline output files" option anywhere.

Comment: Hm, seem so be something wrong on your side. Checked my files: 248kb -> 863kb, 920kb -> 4097kb. My Settings in the Pipeline tool are: Importer: Texture Importer - MonoGame, Processor: Texture - MonoGame, Processor Paramaters: [Some Pink Color], True, False, False, True, False, TextureFormat: Color.
Also, if you have not already, update to the latest MonoGame Version.

Comment: Yea that seems like reasonable file sizes. I have the exact same(default?) pipeline settings. My monogame version is 3.5.1.1679, I'll try to update to 3.6 later if I don't find any other solution I guess

Comment: @PavelSlesinger I've updated to the latest version of Monogame and confirmed it's working correctly. I've cleaned and rebuilt my solution and tried again. I'm still getting 3 gb worth of xnb files.

Comment: Weird. Last thing I can suggest is to go directly to http://community.monogame.net and ask there for help. The community is usualy quite responsive and helpful